# Whats config like renderer in extjs picker?

Tags: extjs, picker, extjs6

I'm developing a web application using Extjs-6. I want to extend a class from `Ext.form.field.Picker`. I do it as follow:

```
...
extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
createPicker: function(){
   return new Ext.panel.Panel({
      items: [{
         xtype: 'textfield',
         name: 'text',
         fielLabel: 'text label'
      }, {
         xtype: 'colorfield',
         name: 'color',
         fielLabel: 'color field'
      }, 
      ...
      ]
   });
}
...
```

my value in this class is an object as follow:

```
{
   text: 'value of textfield',
   color: 'value of colorfield'
}
```

but when I set this object to value of class it shown in picker as `[object object]`.

How Can I d?

Have the picker a confis like `renderer` to get the value of picker and then return correct string?

Comment: I guess you have to overrite `setValue()` method of picker to handle your complex (object) value.

Comment: I can do it, But I don't know what to do with "the string that user see it". I want to be different display string with value of component like date.

Comment: Your problem is that by default picker `setValue()` method try to stringify passed argument. Overrite `setValue()` method to parse its argument if its an object and set it directly if its a string. Save your complex (object) value as `rawValue` and set formatted value to picker field.

Comment: Also you probably can achieve desired result overriting passed object prototype toString() mehtod, but I guess its bad solution as Im not sure that ExtJS call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to it than just template.
Below is example picker implementation for textfield + datefield, just adjust it to have colorfield instead.

```
// component has picker with both textfield and datefield;
// when picker is collapsed, data is displayed as "{text}, {date}"
Ext.define('ColorPicker', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',

    // picker template
    config: {
        popup: {
            lazy: true,
            $value: {
                xtype: 'window',
                closeAction: 'hide',
                referenceHolder: true,
                minWidth: 540,
                minHeight: 60,
                layout: 'form',
                header: false,
                resizable: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'textfield',
                        name: 'text',
                        fielLabel: 'text label',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        reference: 'text'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        name: 'color',
                        fielLabel: 'color field',
                        anchor: '100%',
                        format: 'd.m.Y',
                        reference: 'date'
                    }
                ],
                fbar: [
                    { text: 'OK', reference: 'okBtn' },
                    { text: 'Cancel', reference: 'cancelBtn' }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    dateFormat: 'd.m.Y',

    createPicker: function(){
        var me = this,
            popup = me.getPopup();

        // the window will actually be shown and will house the picker
        me.pickerWindow = popup = Ext.create(popup);

        popup.lookupReference('okBtn').on('click', 'onPickerOk', me);
        popup.lookupReference('cancelBtn').on('click', 'onPickerCancel', me);

        popup.on({
            close: 'onPickerCancel',
            scope: me
        });

        me.updateValue(me.getValue());

        return popup;
    },

    // ok picker button handler
    onPickerOk: function () {
        var me = this,
            popup = me.pickerWindow,
            textField = popup.lookupReference('text'),
            dateField = popup.lookupReference('date'),
            value = {
                text: textField.getValue(),
                date: dateField.getValue()
            };

        popup.hide();

        me.setValue(value);
    },

    // cancel picker button handler
    onPickerCancel: function () {
        var me = this,
            popup = me.pickerWindow;

        popup.hide();

        me.updateValue(me.getValue());
    },

    // override set value to support both string ("{text}, {date}")
    // and object ({ text: "{text}", date: "{date}" })
    setValue: function(value) {
        var me = this,
            text,
            date,
            v;

        if (Ext.isObject(value)) {
            value = value.text + ", " + Ext.Date.format(value.date, me.dateFormat);
        }

        me.callParent([ value ]);

        // always update in case opacity changes, even if value doesn't have it
        // to handle "hex6" non-opacity type of format
        me.updateValue(value);
    },

    // update values in picker fields
    updateValue: function (value) {
        var me = this,
            popup = me.pickerWindow,
            textField,
            dateField,
            text = value.text,
            date = value.date;

        if (!popup || !popup.isComponent) {
            return;
        }

        if (Ext.isString(value)) {
            value = value.split(',');
            text = (value[0] || '').trim();
            date = Ext.Date.parse((value[1] || '').trim(), me.dateFormat);
        } else if (Ext.isObject(value)) {
            text = value.text || '';
            date = value.date || '';
        }

        textField = popup.lookupReference('text');
        dateField = popup.lookupReference('date');

        if (!me.syncing) {
            me.syncing = true;

            textField.setValue(text);
            dateField.setValue(date);

            me.syncing = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14kg